# Android Studio project not reading correctly from SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've been struggling with this for days now and can't work out what's wrong. The thing is, I am not getting errors at the moment. Im just not producing the result I hoped for. I am trying to read from a specific record in my sqlite database where the data is a week ago today - I am trying to get the weather on this day, which is in my database. Here is my DB code for the method I am using:

```
public long homepageTB(){ 

    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

    LocalDate lastWeek = now.minusDays(7+now.getDayOfWeek().getValue()-1);
    LocalDate currentDate = now.minusDays(now.getDayOfWeek().getValue());

    String[] lweek = new String[1];
    lweek[0] = String.valueOf(lastWeek);
    String lastwk = String.valueOf(lastWeek);

    long rv = -1; //<<<< default return to indicate no such row
    SQLiteDatabase DB=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=DB.rawQuery("select weather from dailyQuiz1 where date =?",lweek);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
        rv = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("weather")); 
    }

    System.out.println(lweek[0]);
    System.out.println(rv);

    return rv;
}
```

At the moment, this correctly returns the data week ago in format: 2022-01-31
and returns rv: -1 (which means it can't find the record). However, the record is there in my database:
[image]

So realistically I don't want -1 to be returned as I would want the variable in another class I am calling it from to now hold the value of the weather, which you can see in my database is '**Rainy**'. Any ideas what I've done wrong or what is a better approach? I feel it will be something so obvious but I've been trying so many things for the past few days :( Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

With the exception that you will have an issue with the returned value being 0 if the data is found

- i.e. you are getting a long from a text value when using `rv = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("weather"))` so instead of crashing when trying to convert Rainy to a long 0 is given.

What you have shown works as expected. That leaves the issue to probably be that the database does not in fact contain a row where the date column does  equal the String 2022-01-31.

You  need to ensure that what is in the actual database being used is as expected *(your image appears to be from a tool rather than the actual database and often issues are due to differences)*.

So in Android Studio run the App and get to a point where it is awaiting for user interaction. The click on **App Inspection** do you see the same data? e.g. it should look like (not all columns have been included in the example):-

[image]

If not then your issue is that the data is not being added as expected and that needs to be corrected.

Otherwise click on the Query Icon [image]

Enter and run `SELECT length(date), * FROM dailyquiz1 WHERE date like '2022-01%'` e.g. :-

[image]

- if the first column returned is > 10 then there is an issue with the data that is being stored, as it contains additional data.
- if the first column returned is < 10 then you are storing data that is shorter than it should be.
- if no data is returned then the data stored is even further away from what it should be.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll spend some time going through this information :)